# Iterate over table returned by function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've declared two functions (duplicate_iofs & duplicate_ioftypes) that both return a table after performing INSERT operations :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duplicate_iofs(IN iof_group_src_id integer, IN iof_group_dst_id integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(src_id integer, new_id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    -- DO INSERT REQUESTS
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duplicate_ioftypes(IN iof_group_src_id integer, IN iof_group_dst_id integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(src_id integer, new_id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    -- DO INSERT REQUESTS
END;
```

How can I do something similar like that in a third function :

```
-- 1. Call duplicate_iofs(...) and store the result table (e.g. iofs_table)

-- 2. Call duplicate_ioftypes(...) and store the result table (e.g. ioftypes_table).

-- 3. Iterate through 'iofs_table' and 'ioftypes_table' with nested loops :
FOR iof_row IN SELECT * FROM iofs_table LOOP
    FOR ioftype_row IN SELECT * FROM ioftypes_table LOOP
        -- DO SOMETHING
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

Note : duplicate_iofs() and duplicate_ioftypes() MUST be called only once and thus, MUST NOT be called into the nested loop.

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: Why haven't you used [`INSERT ... RETURNING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) instead of functions?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I prefer to use functions instead of INSERT ... RETURNING to factorize the treatment performed into the functions : these are called by other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE
    curs_iof CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM iofs_table;
    curs_ioftype CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM ioftypes_table;
BEGIN
    OPEN SCROLL curs_iof;
    OPEN SCROLL curs_ioftype;

    FETCH curs_iof INTO iof_row;
    WHILE FOUND LOOP
        FETCH FIRST FROM curs_ioftype INTO ioftype_row;
        WHILE FOUND LOOP

            -- DO SOMETHING

            FETCH curs_ioftype INTO ioftype_row;
        END LOOP;
        FETCH curs_iof INTO iof_row;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE curs_iof;
    CLOSE curs_ioftype;
END;
```

Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).